# Running Calash on iOS 10 physical device -- EHOSTDOWN

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I am trying to test calabash on iOS 10 physical device. I followed these steps for that:

- Enabled UIAutomation on the device using the switch in Settings.app > Developer > Enable UIAutomation
- Both device and Mac are in same network
- Installed app on the device using Xcode
- Ran this command on terminal: 
  $ export BUNDLE_ID=com.example.MyApp-cal (bundle id)
  $ CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Name <>" DEVICE_TARGET= DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://:37265 cucumber

Every time I run this command, calabash is opening DeviceAgent and logging following error on console:

Host is down - connect(2) for  port 37265 (:37265) (Errno::EHOSTDOWN)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: did you instrumented your app with calabash-ios framework ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this error because of some firewall issue. Make sure both device and Mac are on same network. Connect device to Mac using usb.

Launch the app manually on your device. You should check to see if the Calabash server is running.

$ curl http://:37265/version

You should see json output with details of the device and calabash. This means device can run calabash test cases w/o any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around my network's limitations by using a dedicated router.  I was initially using my Mac's wifi as hotspot network to connect all my macs and devices, but that turned out to be flaky, so I got an old Verizon router dedicated to my test setup and have had no connection problems since.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with ensuring the device ip address is correct. Check your device IP address from device and update the run script:

```
export DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://10.0.1.69:37265
```